# WordPress Gravity forms + jQuery + Uploadify issue

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, uploadify, gravity-forms-plugin

For a WordPress plugin, I have to upload some document files (txt, doc) with Uploadify and read it's content with PHP; grab the string and load in to a Gravity forms filed. I was able to do this successfully.

However I want to send the selected file (above) with Gravity forms as file because administrator can see the posted file with the WordPress backed.

Is there a way to set the file name + path by using gravity forms hooks? Or is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: Just a thought, you might be able to rig up something easier via GF + Zapier + Dropbox

Comment: My client wants to upload a file, count it's word and when the user hit the submit button.. gf should send the file.